# Is First Dimension Width or Height while working with Tensorflow/ Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, computer-vision

I've used Keras and Tensorflow by thinking that `Input(shape=(1280,224,1)` will accept as a Tensor of **Grayscale** Image of **Width=1280** and **Height=224** and that is what I had been using for all the pre  trained models in `ResNet` or so by using the `ImagedataGeneratorflow_from_directory(target_size=(1280,224))`.

It is kind of given in the [ResNet50 github Code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/resnet50.py) as **width and height** as:

> input_shape: optional shape tuple, only to be specified
> if `include_top` is False (otherwise the input shape
> has to be `(224, 224, 3)` (with `channels_last` data format)
> or `(3, 224, 224)` (with `channels_first` data format).
> It should have exactly 3 inputs channels,
> and **width and height** should be no smaller than 32.

But Suddenly I stumped across [tf.image.resize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize#args)
where the argument was gives as:

> size: A 1-D int32 Tensor of 2 elements: **new_height, new_width**. The new size for the images

Either my whole had been a mistake or the functionality is different here. Please Help.

Comment: Irrespective of the use case, it always should match the shape of input matrix that you are providing if your input has width first provide as above, if your input has height first then provide height first. It all depends on the shape of input matrix that you are feeding into

Comment: No actually. I just went through the codes. `Conv2d` accepts `height,width,channels` and so does the `.flow_from_directory()`. It uses `numpy` scheme where height is put first and then width.

Comment: yes thats what i am saying it should match input shape, input shape is defined by `rows x columns`, also when you load images into array the shape is defined by `rows x columns`, which we can say that number of rows is height and number of columns are width.

Comment: when you flip a image would you call your height as width, or would call it new_height its upto you, i just wanted to convey that the shape of the matrix will always be defined by `rows x columns`. Hope that clears it

Comment: Oh Okay! got it. I was confused with the `resize` actually. `ImageDataGenerator` and `PIL` uses different schemes and that's when I realized that something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Please correct me but I think I have found the answer. Going through the [Conv2D documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D), I found that:

> **data_format**: A string, one of channels_last (default) or channels_first. The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs. channels_last corresponds to inputs with shape (batch_size, **height, width**, channels) while channels_first corresponds to inputs with shape (batch_size, channels, **height, width**). It defaults to the image_data_format value found in your Keras config file at ~/.keras/keras.json. If you never set it, then it will be channels_last.

So does the [documentation of ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) says:

> data_format    Image data format, either "channels_first" or "channels_last". "channels_last" mode means that the images should have shape (samples, height, width, channels), "channels_first" mode means that the images should have shape (samples, channels, height, width). It defaults to the image_data_format value found in your Keras config file at ~/.keras/keras.json. If you never set it, then it will be "channels_last".

So I think the `tf/Keras` uses `height,width` while `PIL` or `pillow` uses `width,height` format [as the documentation says](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html):

> size – The requested size in pixels, as a 2-tuple: **(width, height)**.

Please correct